# Adjunction space of $D^2 \cup_f S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have the attaching map $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1, z \mapsto z^2$. I am trying to show that $D^2 \cup_f  S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$. Could someone give me a tiny hint?

Unfortunately, I haven't worked with projective planes that much. So I understood that $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all lines going through the origin. Is that right?

Cheers, 
Quizzle

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the adjunction space $D^2 \cup_f S^1$, where $D^2$ is the unit disk.  The space $S^1 \cup_f S^1$ would just be a circle.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for the remark, I edited my post!

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to the quotient of the $2$-sphere $S^2$ by the relation $\sim$ that identifies pairs of antipodal points.

To see why, note that any line through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ cuts the $2$-sphere in two antipodal points.  So we may identify the point of $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ corresponding to a line with a pair of antipodal points in $S^2$.  The topology inherited from $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ is then the usual quotient topology on $S^2/\sim$.