# I'm stuggling with understanding the equivalence relation for the geometric realization of a simplicial complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I tasked myself with triangulating the real projective plane and came up with a triangulation that this website and others agree on heavily. So, I feel confident that I have found the right simplicial complex. The simplicial complex is given by the following picture: [image]  This would mean that the geometric realization of this simplicial complex would be equal to $$(\coprod_{i=1}^{10}\Delta^2_i)\coprod(\coprod_{j=1}^{15}\Delta_j^1)\coprod(\coprod_{k=1}^6\Delta^0)/\sim$$ where $x\sim f^q_m(x)$ where $f^q_m$ is a face map. How do I prove this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the simplicial complex depicted in your question. Its geometric realization is a plane hexagon, i.e. a homeomorphic copy of the closed unit disk $D^2$. You make an identification of the three pairs of edges $[12]$, $[23]$, $[31]$. Transferring to $D^2$ shows that you have the relation $x \sim -x$ for $x \in S^1 \subset D^2$. Thus your quotient space is homeomorphic to $D^2/\sim$.

The latter is a well-known description of $\mathbb R P^2$. See [The real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ is the adjunction space $D^{2} \cup_{f} S^{1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3445764).